# How to make one unique six number from current date and time of the machine?

Tags: php

This is ok but causing duplicate, how to assign machine date and time and apply on that six digit unique?

not working: `sprintf("%0d", mt_rand(1, 999999));`

Comment: Have you tried using `microtime()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
sprintf("%06d", mt_rand(1, 999999));
```

Answer (score 0):

As well, have a look at:

```
uniqid();
```

That could be of use as well...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php